# Can't insert to Xceed DataGridCollectionViewSource.Source a ListCollectionView

Tags: datagrid, listcollectionview, xceed

Getting a System.ArgumentException - 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' is not a valid value for property 'Source'.

I have binded the ItemsSource of the xceed data grid to a ICollectionView in my view model.
Is there any way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

When using the Xceed DataGrid for WPF, you should be binding the ItemsSource property of the DataGridControl to the DataGridCollectionViewSource. By doing this, you will get the best performance out of the DataGrid. Also, the filtering, sorting, grouping, etc.... functionalities  work best with the Xceed's version of the CollectionView. This should definitely help you out!